# EasyImage problems after upgrade to ver. 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I upgraded EasyImage library (https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage) in my project from version 1.3.1 to 3.0.1.

After sync project I get several error messages. I am just an amateur programmer who is learning, so solving these errors is a bit beyond me.

Let me detail:

```
import pl.aprilapps.easyphotopicker.DefaultCallback;
import pl.aprilapps.easyphotopicker.EasyImage;
import static pl.aprilapps.easyphotopicker.EasyImage.openChooserWithGallery;
```

Get next error message: "error: cannot find symbol static openChooserWithGallery".

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (data != null) {
            filePath = data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH);
            String fileName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            mFileName.setText(fileName);
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    EasyImage.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, this, new DefaultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onImagePickerError(Exception e, EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {
            Toast.makeText(NewTrackActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.error_image), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onImagePicked(File imageFile, EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {
            isImageAdded = true;
            mPhotoImageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
        }
    });
}
```

errors:

1. error: cannot find symbol class ImageSource
2. error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method onMediaFilesPicked(MediaFile[],MediaSource) in Callbacks
3. error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
4. error: non-static method handleActivityResult(int,int,Intent,Activity,Callbacks) cannot be referenced from a static context

and for

```
private void addPhoto() {
    final String chooserTitle = getString(R.string.title_add_track_image);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            openChooserWithGallery(this, chooserTitle, 0);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_no_camera_permission, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        openChooserWithGallery(this, chooserTitle, 0);
    }
}
```

error: cannot find symbol method openChooserWithGallery(NewTrackActivity,String,int)

I followed all details from EasyImage documentation. WIth version 1.3.1 work perfect, but with ver. 3.0.1 all was mess up.

I inspired from this sample code https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/pl/aprilapps/easyphotopicker/sample/MainActivity.java

Comment: There are detailed instruction on how to use the library with respect to the latest version on the landing page (ReadMe).

Comment: If you dive in into the EasyImage library you will find out every intent it supports here https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage/blob/master/library/src/main/java/pl/aprilapps/easyphotopicker/Intents.kt. Take a look at ```plainGalleryPickerIntent``` sometimes it´s just a rename.

Comment: Also, the library works with a Builder patter, so you can create your Chooser there new EasyImage.Builder(this)
                .setChooserTitle("Pick media")
                .setCopyImagesToPublicGalleryFolder(false)
//                .setChooserType(ChooserType.CAMERA_AND_DOCUMENTS)
                .setChooserType(ChooserType.CAMERA_AND_GALLERY)
                .setFolderName("EasyImage sample")
                .allowMultiple(true)
                .build();

Comment: thanks for support! I solved.